# Maximum number of detections for object detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-coral, pycoral

I would like to perform an object detection task using pycoral's USB Accelerator.
I think I can set the number of detections with the parameter "top_k", but what is the maximum value I can set for top_k?

I am using python 3.10. We are using GCP to create the model.
Currently, we cannot have more than 40 detections.

I checked the following website, but there was no specific mention of it.
[text](https://coral.ai/docs/reference/py/pycoral.adapters/#module-pycoral.adapters.detect)

Thank you in advance.